# A walk into the desert and back - have some hard-won answers but can't see the pattern

Tags: optimization, puzzle, operations-research

> **Mission**: To find a minimum-length walk from "base" to a point *g* distance units away and back for 1 person alone, given:
>
> 1. An unlimited supply of rations provided at base, to be consumed continuously while walking.
> 2. The ability to walk up to 1 distance unit per unit of rations consumed.
> 3. The ability to carry no more than 2 total units of rations at a time, including those about to be consumed.
> 4. The ability to walk away from and return to sealed rations only, i.e. rations in full 1-unit packages kept sealed since leaving base. Of course each such package has to be unsealed for any of its contents to be consumed.

Let us assume we have a rule that no more than 1 unit of rations is available (ready to be consumed without an unsealing) at any given time and that an increase in available rations always implies an unsealing. (Such a rule is not really required, but explaining why requires some wordy lemmas and would distract from what I am trying to ask.)

Using a long-running simplex algorithm computer program, I think I have found minimum walks for *g* between 1 and 195/64 (= 3.046875) distance units, and I would like to do the same for even greater values of *g*.

But first, I would really like to find a way to cut down on the computation time, if possible, by eliminating a bifurcation of my objective function.

Total walk length, to be minimized, equals twice the amount of walking toward *g* (because we end where we begin); and the amount of walking toward *g* has to include the sum of distances from base of all unsealings (because all sealed packages begin at base and no more than 1 can move at a time), plus the distance to *g* from the nearest unsealing (because the person has to get to *g* even if no unsealing occurs there).

It is that nearest unsealing that causes the bifurcation. My constraints have to distinguish unsealings before reaching *g* from unsealings after reaching *g* because the contents of the packages unsealed **after** reaching *g* cannot be used to move any packages unsealed **before** reaching *g*.

So I have been having to run the dual simplex algorithm twice for each value of *g*, once with an objective that assumes the closest unsealing to *g* happens no **later** than the arrival at *g*, and once with an objective that assumes the closest unsealing to *g* happens no **earlier** than the arrival at *g*. Then the result with the smaller minimum walk is my answer.

I find it interesting that none of the results I have gotten so far put the 2 closest unsealings to *g* equal to each other.

**Question 1:** Is it impossible to minimize walking with the 2 closest unsealings to *g* > 1 equal?

**Question 2:** Is there a clue here as to how to eliminate the bifurcation?

Comment: 1) Is it a homework 2) If yes, is it in an Operational Research lecture ?

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97419

Comment: Not homework. Just a curiosity based on Dudeney's "Exploring Mount Neverest", which I've been trying to understand for 20 years.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46585247_Exploring_Mount_Neverest) ?

Comment: Yes. I was in contact with the author years ago, but he apparently got too busy to answer my emails.

Comment: Answer to second part of Question 1: Yes, for all g > 1 no minimum can occur with a = b. Answer to Question 2: Yes, there is definitely a way to find a minimum with the appropriate set of equations using the dual simplex algorithm, without resorting to an either-or constraint.

Answer (score 4):

We shall assume the artificial rule already mentioned, so the amount of walking between consecutive unsealings will always be at least zero and at most 1 unit, and we shall follow the convention of using the same names for locations as for their respective distances from base, and answer Questions 1 and 2 assuming *g* > 1.

Let *g′* = *g* − ½, and let *I* be any valid itinerary that fulfills the mission, i.e. in which the person reaches *g* and then returns to base. Since *g′* > ½, there must be at least one location between base and *g′* where in *I* the person changes direction, unseals a package, or walks away from stationary rations. Let *g″* be the closest such location to *g′*.

**Lemma 1:** For any valid itinerary *I* that fulfills the round-trip-to-*g* mission, there exists an itinerary *I′* fulfilling the same mission in which the person takes the same actions between base and *g″* and does only 2(*g* − *g″*) units of walking between *g″* and *g*.

**Proof of Lemma 1:**

Let *m*<sub>b</sub> be the moment in *I* of the person’s last departure from *g″* **before** reaching *g* and *m*<sub>a</sub> the moment of their next arrival at *g″*, **after** reaching *g*. Between *m*<sub>b</sub> and *m*<sub>a</sub>, the person must walk from *g″* to *g*, a distance of *g* − *g″* units, and then from *g* back to *g″*, a further *g* − *g″* units, and may change direction multiple times and may unseal multiple packages. Since the person has to cover more than 1 unit of distance in that interval, at least one unsealing must occur between *m*<sub>b</sub> and *m*<sub>a</sub>. Let *m*<sub>y</sub> be the moment of the first such unsealing.

Altering *I* by replacing all walking beyond *g″* with just consuming the same rations without walking anywhere would give us a valid itinerary for a round trip to *g″* with some wasting of rations at *g″*. But the unsealing at *m*<sub>y</sub> is unnecessary in such an itinerary because the amount of walking between *m*<sub>x</sub>, the moment of the latest unsealing before *m*<sub>y</sub> (the beginning of the mission if none), and *m*<sub>z</sub>, the moment of the first unsealing after *m*<sub>y</sub> (the end of the mission if none), which is no more than 2 units in *I*, invariably gets reduced to 1 unit or less by the alteration: If *m*<sub>y</sub> is the only unsealing between *m*<sub>b</sub> and *m*<sub>a</sub>, then the whole interval from *m*<sub>b</sub> to *m*<sub>a</sub>, in which walking gets reduced from greater than 1 unit to zero, is contained within the interval from *m*<sub>x</sub> to *m*<sub>z</sub>, and otherwise *m*<sub>z</sub> occurs before *m*<sub>a</sub> so that walking between *m*<sub>y</sub> and *m*<sub>z</sub> gets reduced to zero, leaving only the walking between *m*<sub>x</sub> and *m*<sub>y</sub>, 1 unit or less, between *m*<sub>x</sub> and *m*<sub>z</sub>.

Since all rations begin at base and only 1 sealed package can be carried at a time, the person must have, at some point prior to *m*<sub>y</sub>, departed from *g″* carrying a sealed package toward *g′* when there were no rations at or beyond *g′*. Let *m*<sub>i</sub> be the latest such time before *m*<sub>y</sub>, and let *m*<sub>j</sub> be the moment of the person’s next arrival back at *g″* after *m*<sub>i</sub>.

Altering *I* by eliminating both all walking beyond *g″* and the unnecessary unsealing at *m*<sub>y</sub> gives us a valid itinerary for a round trip to *g″* in which there is at least 1 sealed package at *g″* at all times after *m*<sub>i</sub>. Call this altered itinerary *J*. Assuring that the sealed package being carried at *m*<sub>i</sub> is never unsealed or even carried back toward base after *m*<sub>i</sub> in *J* is not a real restriction. Since all sealed packages are the same, the person can always, whenever an unsealing or removal is required after *m*<sub>i</sub>, choose a different package to unseal or carry away and leave that particular package undisturbed.

If *m*<sub>i</sub> = *m*<sub>b</sub>, then in *I* the person has to be carrying at least 2(*g* − *g″*) units more rations at *m*<sub>i</sub> = *m*<sub>b</sub> than at *m*<sub>j</sub> = *m*<sub>a</sub>, including a sealed package, in order to walk to *g* and return to *g″*. Otherwise, between *m*<sub>i</sub> and *m*<sub>j</sub> in *I*, the person takes a sealed package to *g′* or beyond and returns to *g″*, so in this case too the person has to be carrying at least 2(*g* − *g″*) more rations at *m*<sub>i</sub> than at *m*<sub>j</sub>, 1 sealed package plus 2(*g′* − *g″*).

If the difference in rations being carried between *m*<sub>i</sub> and *m*<sub>j</sub> is greater than 2(*g* − *g″*), the excess can be discarded or consumed without walking at the corresponding point in *I′*. Then in *I′* the person can simply walk directly to *g* and back, consuming exactly 2(*g* − *g″*) units of rations, and the part of *I′* beginning at the point corresponding to *m*<sub>j</sub> will suffice to return the person to base. The sealed package being carried at *m*<sub>i</sub> will of course need to be unsealed at the exact moment when the other rations inevitably get used up. If the unsealing will happen after the person reaches *g*, the person can even leave the package at its unsealing location when on the way to *g*. Q.E.D.

**Answer to Question 1:** At least 1 unsealing must occur between *m*<sub>b</sub> and *m*<sub>a</sub>, when the person is beyond *g″*, so if the 2 closest unsealing positions to *g* are equal in some valid itinerary *I*, they must both occur beyond *g″*, and this requires more than 2(*g* − *g″*) units of walking beyond *g″* in *I*. But by Lemma 1 there exists an itinerary *J* with less walking, so **yes**, it is impossible to minimize walking with the 2 closest unsealing positions to *g* > 1 equal.

**Answer to Question 2:**

Let M<sub>1</sub> be the original mission, a round trip to *g*, and let M<sub>2</sub> be the alternative mission of a round trip to *g′* in which a sealed package remains at *g′* at the end.

There are at least 2 clues in the answer to Question 1: (1) that the mininum rations required for a round-trip between *g″* and *g* is less than the maximum load of 2 units and is equal to the minimum rations required for a round trip between *g″* and *g′* that leaves 1 sealed pack at *g′*, and (2) that an optimal itinerary for M<sub>1</sub> always includes a minimum-length round-trip between *g″* and *g*.

From the clues and the method used for Lemma 1, we can prove that any itinerary for M<sub>2</sub> can be converted into an itinerary for M<sub>1</sub> by adding exactly 1 more unit of walking, and that any optimal itinerary for M<sub>1</sub> can be converted into an itinerary for M<sub>2</sub> with exactly 1 unit less walking. This implies that any optimal itinerary for M<sub>2</sub> can be converted into an optimal itinerary for M<sub>1</sub>. An optimal itinerary for M<sub>2</sub> can be calculated without the variable that causes the bifurcation, the position of the unsealing at *m*<sub>y</sub> in any itinerary for M<sub>1</sub>, and that position can be calculated as part of the conversion to an optimal itinerary for M<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: This is identical to the deleted answer by the same user.

Comment: I tried replacing the long-deleted answer with this new one and couldn't, so I made it a new answer.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ The deleted answer was deleted by a moderator last year, as (at the time) the answer was more of a comment than an answer.  Now, *a year later*, the original answerer has tried to post a more complete answer.  Since the earlier answer was mod-deleted, they cannot undelete it, and have appropriately posted a *new* answer.  There is nothing wrong here, and votes to delete the new answer should *not* be based on the fact that it is a duplicate.